# How to add local Git server account in Xcode 9?

Tags: git, github, xcode9

We all know that Xcode 9 provide's so many support of Github such as clone, commit, pull, push etc. There is an option on Xcode->preferences to add GitHub account. Here is a screenshot below.

[image]

I can add a my Remote(public) GitHub account. We have a private Git server in our office and we access it using this ip (192.168.1.15), but I can not add this Git server account on my Xcode. I already add my personal public GitHub account(shamiul110107) shown in screen bellow.

My question is that how can I add my private Git server account in Xcode 9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by your 'local Git account'? Do you mean a local git repository? You don't need an 'account' for git repositories on your local machine.

Comment: I update my question. Please see this.@scott Newson

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot add a "Git server account", and you don't need to. This has nothing to do with Accounts; you're looking in the wrong place.

If the question is how to clone from a remote repository, choose Source Control -> Clone and enter the required information. Or clone using the command line. Either way, once you have a clone, there is nothing else to do, as the clone contains the remote info.

Comment: But I can add my public Git account. I am able to create repository, clone, push, pull etc from my Xcode and not using command line. But I can not do it my Private Git server.

Comment: No. You can add your _GitHub_ account. That is not a repository; it's a GitHub _account_. Similar to an email account. Similar to an Apple ID! You can downvote me all you like; you asked how Xcode 9 works and _I'm telling you how it works_. You don't have to like it, but what I'm saying is perfectly true. The feature where you enter account info for repositories in the Accounts prefs is _gone_.

Comment: Though your answer is not exactly as I asked but it solves my another problem about cloning.

Answer (score 2):

@Samiul Islam Sami

In previous versions of `Xcode` , ie. prior to `Xcode9` you can add your local `Git` Server account. From `Xcode9` that feature has been removed and `Github` has been integrated with `Xcode` which allows you to have a control over your `Github` `repositories` within `Xcode9`. However you can still use your `Git` `Server` from office without adding an account to `Xcode`.

1. Open `Xcode`
2. Source Control -> `Clone`
3. add the repository URL from your local Git Server (Here I'm using a git Repository from `GitHub` without adding any account to my `Xcode`)
4. Press `Clone` and Select the save location
5. The project will create a local repository in your PC
6. You can add changes and `commit` and then `push`

while pushing to the local `Git` Server ,user credentials is required , which in your case is your **username** and **password** for your local  Git Server account.

images added below:- 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a local repository that you need to push to a remote, you can use the command-line to add that remote:

1. Login to the remote server and create a bare repo if it does not
   exist: `git init --bare repo.git`
2. Close Xcode on the local machine.
3. `cd` to the Xcode project directory.
4. Add a remote: `git remote add origin ssh://username@host:port/path-to-repo.git`
5. Open Xcode project. You should be able to **Source Control > Push** to the new remote.